# Generating a graph with Pandas from a CSV file using Python and dtypes of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, graph

This question may be elementary. The background is this: I am attempting to build a graph in Python from a CSV file. Ideally, it would look something like this:

[image]

This suggests to me that a [Sankey diagram](https://www.data-to-viz.com/graph/sankey.html) would be a good choice, although what I really have in mind is the production of something like a "road map" or "highway map." What I am really mapping are logical dependency relations: nodes here represent theorems, and an edge should be drawn between nodes when one theorem's proof cites another ("flowing" from the earlier theorem T to any later theorem that cites T).

To do this, I am loading a CSV file with all the theorems (nodes) in one column, PM['pmnum'], and all the theorems to which an edge should connect it in another column, i.e. all the theorems that use that node in a proof, in another column, PM['pmproof'].

Using pandas, it was easy enough to convert the CSV file to a DataFrame. My trouble is in generating the graph itself from the DataFrame. When I build it using

```
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(PM, 'pmnum', 'pmproof')
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)
plt.show(G)
```

the image looks like this:

[image]

My suspicion is that the lack of edges is produced by the columns of the DataFrame having different dtypes; the PM['pmnum'] column has dtype float, and the PM['pmprop'] column has dtype object. This is because when I run

```
print(G.edges)
```

I get a very long output that includes pairs like this: ('1.2', 2.08), ('1.2', 2.4). Similarly, when I run

```
print(G.nodes)
```

I get a long output in an array that includes entries seemingly of different types, e.g., 2.05, '1.6', 2.06, '2.04'. And when I run print (PM.dtypes), I get that pmnum has dtype float64 and pmproof has dtype object.

This in turn be caused by the following: in the initial CSV file, the two columns to be used for the graph include a float and an array, e.g., column 1 has

> 1.2

and column 2 has (for example)

> 2.01, 2.05, 2.3

This might be leading to the difference in dtype when I alter the DataFrame to separate out each entry of this array. There I first separate the string and then use the explode() function to make sure that, e.g., 1.2 is connected to each entry 2.01, 2.05, and 2.3 (and not to, e.g., an array containing all of them).

Is the difference in dtype what is causing the issue? If so, is there a way to fix it, e.g., by changing the dtype of one or the other column? And what dtypes *should* the columns have in order to generate the graph? Below is the code from my Jupyter Notebook. Thanks in advance for any help. EDIT: also included is a sample of the data: https://ln.sync.com/dl/ecd0fa150/7wrdt3n4-xg4ca3jv-5f4tyyey-st9wp5jm.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly as pl
import plotly.graph_objects as go 
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sn
import dash as ds
import xmltodict
import csv
import unicodedata
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
import plotly.io as pio
pio.renderers.default='notebook'

%This is where I load the DataFrame.
PM = pd.read_csv('PM.csv', sep=',')

%This is where I explode the array to make sure the node has an edge for every entry of that array.
PM = pd.read_csv('PM.csv', sep=',')
PM['pmproof'] = PM['pmproof'].str.split(', ')
PM = PM.explode('pmproof')

%This is where I plot the graph
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(PM, 'pmnum', 'pmproof')
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)
plt.show(G)
```

Comment: I suggest pasting some sample lines from `PM.csv`, enough to enable SO users to run this code block and reproduce the issue on their local machines.

Comment: Yes please post sample data from your `csv`. `df.head(20)` should do.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this omission. A sample of the data (~30 rows) has now been posted via a link to a downloadable CSV file.

Comment: When reproducing your issue I found that the edges do actually show. It is likely they were simply not visible in your case because of the small size of the graph.

Comment: Thanks very much @RJAdriaansen. I see now that adding, e.g., "linewidths=20" to the nx.draw function makes the edges appear. Unfortunately, the nodes seem to be duplicated by the from_pandas_edgelist function. Ideally, the graph would be built by making everything PM.['pmnum'] a node, and then drawing edges between these nodes whenever a node appears in PM.['pmproof'] in the same row as PM.['pmnum']. Is it the difference in dtypes causing duplication of nodes, or the explode function? If not, my question is now different, and I will, I guess, close this question and revisit the drawing board.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to RJ Adriaansen's answer, I noticed that the edges do exist but where too thin to see. And I changed the 'pmproof' column to a float using

```
PM['pmproof'] = PM.pmproof.astype(float)
```

It turns out that this removed the duplicated nodes that separated the edges too much. Here's a quick resulting Sankey graph with the fix (built in a hurry with [Ken Lok's genSankey function](https://medium.com/kenlok/how-to-create-sankey-diagrams-from-dataframes-in-python-e221c1b4d6b0)):

[image: Sankey diagram of Principia through *5]